# Hide / remove string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

So i have this:

```
jQuery('.amount').each(function() {
    console.log(jQuery(this).text());
    var text = jQuery(this).text().replace("Gratuit !", " ");
    jQuery(this).text(text);
});
```

It works fine with another element but not this one. The console returns the right numbers of other strings but can't seems to get the number of "Gratuit !" strings which is in a modal, but so are the others strings.

http://www.taomedecine.com/#seminaires
It's on the quick view of the "chrono accupuncture" product.

Comment: "chrono accupuncture" product doesn't seems to have that tag `.amount`

Comment: It does. It's the class of the span that contains the product price in the modal.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're calling that function **before** the `.amount` elements **exist** on the page. Your modal probably loads its content (containing the `.amount` elements) **asynchronously**.

If you look at the **console** when you load the page you link to, you can see it doesn't console.log() anything from:

```
console.log(jQuery(this).text());
```

That gives you a clue that the .each(), loops **0** items.

Therefore, you should call the function you mention **after** the model content has been loaded, in it's **callback function** assuming it provides one.

Comment: The thing is it does loop the "5,00€" items with the .amount selector and this price is also in the modal. That's why i'm confused. It's not working only with that string.

Comment: They already exist on the page when it loads, if you view source on the page, and search for class="amount" it only shows those. It doesn't have the string 'Gratuit !' anywhere on the page.

Comment: Damn you're right. I'm afraid i can't just edit the woocommerce plugin code in case of an update by the client. It would erase the function.